# jQuery Masonry rendering "row blocks" instead of fitting elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

A simple usage of jQuery masonry plugin is placing images in "blocks" instead of fitting elements in the empty spaces. The figure explains by itself:

[image]

Is there a way to fix (or at least minimize) those "voids"?

HTML:

```
<!-- this overlay has height 100%, no scroll and position fixed -->
<div class='overlay-container'>

  <!-- the inner container is "scroll-able": -->
  <div class='row' id='ms-container'>

    <!-- masonry items... -->
    <div class='col-md-4 ms-item'>
      <div class='boxcontainer'>
        <img src="photo.png" />
        <h1>
          <a href='#'>
            activity_2
          </a>
        </h1>
      </div>
    </div>
   <!-- more items... -->

  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var $container = $('#ms-container');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
    $container.masonry({

        itemSelector: '.ms-item',
        columnWidth: '.ms-item',
        transitionDuration: 0.4

    });

    });
```

CSS:

```
.overlay-container {
    height: 100% !important; 
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    width: 58%;
    left: 30px;
    padding: 50px 10px 10px 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.boxcontainer {
    border:1px solid #ededed;
    background:#fff;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:center;
    transition:border 500ms ease-out;
    border-bottom:medium double #ddd;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a working fiddle for this?

Comment: The figure explains the classic usage of a "masonry" (or pinterest) layout. What are you trying to accomplish? You should also provide a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to work with masonry in project with bootstrap 3, but I've given up. Instead I used [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html) that was much more easier.
I made an example using your structure, [check it out](https://jsfiddle.net/4c0dsyqw/).
Just pay attention in the 'relative container' it's important to plugin don't get lost.

> HTML

```
<!-- this overlay has height 100%, no scroll and position fixed -->
<div class='overlay-container'>
  <div class="relative">
    <!-- the inner container is "scroll-able": -->
    <div class='row' id='ms-container'>

      <!-- masonry items... -->
      <div class='col-md-4 ms-item'>
        <div class='boxcontainer'>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/300x500" />
          <h1>
            <a href='#'>
              activity_2
            </a>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>

     <!-- more items... -->

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

> CSS

```
.overlay-container {
    height: 100% !important; 
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    width: 58%;
    left: 30px;
    padding: 50px 10px 10px 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.boxcontainer {
    border:1px solid #ededed;
    background:#fff;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:center;
    transition:border 500ms ease-out;
    border-bottom:medium double #ddd;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.relative { position:relative; }
```

> JavaScript

```
$("#ms-container.row").isotope({
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: ".col-md-4"
    },
    itemSelector: ".ms-item",
    percentPosition: !0,
    layoutMode: "masonry"
});
```

Hope this helps.